# Reapers, Combat Drugs, and Medivacs

Tags: starcraft-2

The Terran unit "Reaper" has the ability to quickly heal when out of combat (when not fired upon or firing). It's a great opening unit, both for scouting and for picking off workers for you to get ahead, even forcing unit production.
It's also a great unit later on, for the same purposes as mentioned above.

But if I would like to drop reapers in the back of an enemy base to do some worker killing and quickly pick them up and fly to another base, so my question is:

**Will the Reaper´s Combat Drug work when inside the medivac?**

Is Reaper "out of combat" inside the Medivac?

Comment: I think the drug also works in a bunker so it would stand to reason it works for a medivac, there is a unittester custom map you can test this yourself (search for hots unittester)

Comment: Why would Reapers combat drugs and Medivacs?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but marines are a better choice than reapers for medivac drops. More DPS than reapers and ability to use stim. Cheaper too. +1 for interesting mechanic question though.

Comment: @OrcJMR I know the question is odd, but I am thinking about the possibilies in this. Instead of doing whats expected regarding drops. Reapers have a greater mobility from being droped in the main to easilty move the NE. From there back into the Medivac into the 3rd / 4th expo. Also saving the boost instead of using it at first.

Comment: The question is perfectly fine. What is odd is lack of commas in the title, which makes the word "combat" a verb - if the grammar is English, of course.

Comment: @OrcJMR English is not my first language. Sorry for the missing commas

Comment: No problem, I tried to joke :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Reaper is considered "Out of Combat" as long as it is neither taking damage *nor shooting*.

So while combat drugs won't work in a bunker the reaper is shooting out of, reapers can never shoot out of medivacs, so they'll be out of combat within 10 seconds of being picked up (or less!). This is kinda similar to how zerg units will continue to regen while in a nydus network or overlord (though at a much slower rate).

But that said, I'm not sure why you'd want to do reaper drops -- Hellions are cheaper and deal bonus damage to workers.

Comment: They only do bonus damage with the Infernal Pre-ignighter upgrade now. They removed the +damage to light in the last patch.

Comment: @Sorean Area damage is still there though. A drop of 4 hellions can wreck a lot more than 8 reapers, even without upgrades.

Comment: I agree that the splash effect is still there, but they way it's worded it's implying that they inherently come with a bonus even if it's attacking just one worker.